# Setting local storage for collapse link inside menu

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a collapse link inside a menu and the sub menus comes down on clicking the link, but if the page is refreshed , it closes by itself. I don't know how to implement the local storage for this. Please help me. Thank you for your time.  I have added my current code below.

Code:

```js
const linkCollapse = document.getElementsByClassName('collapse__link')
var i

for (i = 0; i < linkCollapse.length; i++) {
  linkCollapse[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    const collapseMenu = this.nextElementSibling
    collapseMenu.classList.toggle('showCollapse')


    const rotate = collapseMenu.previousElementSibling
    rotate.classList.toggle('rotate')
  })
}
```

```html
<body id="body-pd">

  <div class="l-navbar" id="navbar">
      <nav class="nav">
          <div>
              <div class="nav__brand">
                  <ion-icon name="menu-outline" class="nav__toggle" id="nav-toggle"></ion-icon>
                  <!-- <a href="#" class="nav__logo"><img src="images/smartmine1.png" height="80" width="90" style="margin-right: 40px;"></a> -->
                  <a href="#" class="nav__logo"><img src="images/smartmine.png" height="60" width="175" style="margin-right: 40px;"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="nav__list">
                  <a href="Dashboard.php" class="nav__link active">
                      <ion-icon name="home-outline" class="nav__icon"></ion-icon>
                      <span class="nav__name">Dashboard</span>
                  </a>


                  <div  class="nav__link collapse">
                      <ion-icon name="settings-outline" class="nav__icon"></ion-icon>
                      <span class="nav__name">Equipment</span>

                      <ion-icon name="chevron-down-outline" class="collapse__link"></ion-icon>

                      <ul class="collapse__menu">
                          <ion-icon class="icon3"name="contrast-outline"></ion-icon> <a href="lights.php" class="collapse__sublink">Lighting Plant</a> <br>
                                                         <ion-icon class ="icon3"name="videocam-outline"></ion-icon>  <a href="" class="collapse__sublink">IP Cameras</a><br>
                                                         <!-- <ion-icon class="icon3" name="water-outline"></ion-icon> <a href="" class="collapse__sublink">Pumping Stations</a> -->

                                                      </ul>
                  </div>

                  <a href="Analytics.php" class="nav__link">
                      <ion-icon name="pie-chart-outline" class="nav__icon"></ion-icon>
                      <span class="nav__name">Analytics</span>
                  </a>

              </div>
          </div>

          <a href="#" class="nav__link">
              <ion-icon name="log-out-outline" class="nav__icon"></ion-icon>
              <span class="nav__name">Log Out</span>

          </a>
      </nav>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you add your html codes too here.

Comment: Yes!! I just edited the question